# how to import a long list of data in python?

Tags: python, list

I have two columns of data in a webpage, the data is written like this:

```
1         0.12
2         0.35
3         1.00
4        -0.48
5         0.78
.
.
.
1000      0.84
```

As you see, it is a thousand lines stored in a webpage. I wanted to know how I can have these data in two lists such that list A=[1,2,3,...,1000] and list B=[0.12,0.35,1,-0.48,0.78,...,0.84]
Obviously I can have list A by the code **range(1,1001)** but I do not know how to import list B.

Comment: Hi. Have you tried playing around with lists or Googling "reading data into lists"? Is there some code you wrote which didn't work?

Comment: do you want to import this data by copy-pasting into your program, or reading the webpage from python?

Comment: Actually it doesn't matter. I wana learn both ways. But thanks for giving me the keywords for googling. I am kind of new in python.

Comment: Please post a sample of the file you're reading from.  And welcome to Python :-)

Comment: As @Jesuisme said, please provide the webpage. If there is HTML formatting or tags other than what you show in your small example, the answer to the question could be entirely different.

Comment: Are the two columns relational, meaning do they build a row of data? or are you just collecting the two columns for separate operations?

Comment: @JohnK the columns are related like this: experiment 1 has the result of 0.12, experiment 2 has the result of 0.35 and so on.

Comment: I found a way to import the data that is stored in the webpage by this:def get_page(url):
    try:
        import urllib
        return urllib.urlopen(url).read()
    except:
        return "1"

Comment: But I still cannot understand how to put the second column in a list.

Answer (score 0):

Error checking aside, the following should work.

```py
listA = list()
listB = list()
with open('data.dat', 'r') as istr:
    for line in istr:
        words = line.split()
        if (words):  # skip blank lines
            listA.append(int(words[0]))
            listB.append(float(words[1]))
```

Comment: This will not work if the webpage uses some kind of HTML formatting.

Comment: Thank you, I am a new user of python. I should analyze the codes that u wrote. I do not know some of them. In case I had a problem I am gonna leave a comment.

Comment: @Zenadix That's correct, but then he'd have to tell us what the format is.  The example in the question shows plain text.  Note anyway that you can use eg `lynx -dump http:://www.xample.com/data.html` to quickly transform a HTML page into formatted plain text.

Answer (score 0):

If you are already reading the data line by line from the site and the Data is relational I suguest you use a dictionary

```
myDictionary={}

with open("t.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        #line.split() will split line data by whitespace characters if your webpage lines are delimited another way you can use line.split(delimiter) 
        #.split() does exactly like it sounds like, it splits a line of data by a delimiter into a list
        #in this case we split the line into a list called items then we can call the two items and add them to a relational dictionary
        items = line.split()
        myDictionary[items[0]] = items[1]

for item in sorted(myDictionary.keys()):
    print "line values: %s, %s" % (item,myDictionary[item])
```

This would output something like:

```
line values: 1, 0.12
line values: 2, 0.35
line values: 3, 1.00
line values: 4, -0.48
line values: 5, 0.78
etc...
```

[Python Dictionaries Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

[Python split Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)